# Mass of dark matter

Tags: astrophysics, mass

The Alcubierre warp equation specifies that negative mass is required for said "warp drive" to function properly. Could dark matter  provide the negative mass that's required?

Comment: No because dark matter doesn't have negative mass.

Comment: To answer the now deleted comment: we know the dark matter is there because of it's gravitational effect which is that of a positive energy density.